# How to dynamically set styles to another page anchor tag from different page in asp.net

Tags: jquery, asp.net, css

I have "Home Page" with header DIV and two iframes which is divided left and right. Left side i loaded Menu Tree View page. 
Header div contain few anchor tag with some styles and styles written in Jquery. When user click anchor tag it will highlighted.
When user clicks left side frame (menu), if anchor tag is highlighted in the header div then i must remove the highlighted styles. Can any one please tell me how to do this?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>Home Page</title>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Css/HomePageStyle.css" type="text/css" />

    <!-- Import JQuery Plugins -->
    <script type="text/jscript" src="jquery/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/jscript" src="jquery/jquery-ui-1.10.3.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css" />

    <script type="text/javascript" src="JavaScript/DisableBackSpace.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="JavaScript/DisableMouseRightClick.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#lnkHomePage').click(function () {
                $('#lnkHomePage').css('background-color', '#498120');
                $('#lnkHomePage').css('color', '#fff');

                $('#lnkMyProf').css('background-color', '#fff');
                $('#lnkMyProf').css('color', '#556B2F');

                $('#lnkChgPwd').css('background-color', '#fff');
                $('#lnkChgPwd').css('color', '#556B2F');
            });

            $('#lnkMyProf').click(function () {
                $('#lnkMyProf').css('background-color', '#498120');
                $('#lnkMyProf').css('color', '#fff');

                $('#lnkChgPwd').css('background-color', '#fff');
                $('#lnkChgPwd').css('color', '#556B2F');

                $('#lnkHomePage').css('background-color', '#fff');
                $('#lnkHomePage').css('color', '#556B2F');
            });

            $('#lnkChgPwd').click(function () {
                $('#lnkChgPwd').css('background-color', '#498120');
                $('#lnkChgPwd').css('color', '#fff');

                $('#lnkHomePage').css('background-color', '#fff');
                $('#lnkHomePage').css('color', '#556B2F');

                $('#lnkMyProf').css('background-color', '#fff');
                $('#lnkMyProf').css('color', '#556B2F');
            });

        });
    </script>

</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div class="header">
        <div class="lefttext">
            Welcome
        </div>
        <div class="righttext">
            <div>
                <label id="lblLoginUserName" runat="server"></label> <p>|</p>
            </div>
            <div>
                <a id="lnkHomePage" href="welcomepage.aspx" target="mainFrame">Home</a> <p>|</p>
            </div>
            <div>
                <a id="lnkMyProf" href="myprofile.aspx" target="mainFrame">My profile</a> <p>|</p>
            </div>
            <div>
                <a id="lnkChgPwd" href="ChangePassword.aspx" target="mainFrame">Change password</a> <p>|</p>
            </div>
            <div>
                <a href="">Logout</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <table cellspacing="0" id="main">
        <tr>
            <td class="leftnav">
                <div class="leftnavheader">
                    Menu</div>
                <div class="menu">
                    <iframe src="MenuItem.aspx" frameborder="0" style="height: 94.5%; width: 100%;" name="menuFrame">
                    </iframe>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td class="content">
                <div class="MainFrame" id="MainDiv" runat="server">
                    <iframe src="WelcomePage.aspx" id="maincontentpageframe" style="width: 100%; height: 99.2%;"
                        frameborder="1" name="mainFrame" runat="server"></iframe>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    </form>
</body>
</html>*
```

Comment: It would be more useful if you'd prepare a fiddle instead of pasting your whole client-side code here.

Comment: Thanks for ur instruction. Henceforth i'll do it.